# React/Redux ComponentWillMount isn't loading data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Working with a React based app with Redux for state, and I have a component that is supposed to load up a list of data from the back end on load.

I have the component loading, with state and actions mapped. I have the main data call for the component here:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.loadTasks(this.props.user);
}
```

which fires the action function here:

```
export const loadTaskList = (user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3201/tasks/${user._id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(tasks => {
          console.dir(tasks);
          return({type: LOAD_TASKS, payload: tasks});
        });
  }
}
```

which gets sent to the reducer, and incorporated into the store like this:

```
export default (state=initState, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case LOAD_TASKS:
      console.log(`Payload of tasks: ${payload}`);
      return{...state, tasks: payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The question is why this isn't getting into my state, and therefore in my component?

Edit: just for clarity, my mapState, and mapActions objects:

```
let mapState = (state) => ({
  tasks: state.tasklist,
  user: state.user
});

let mapActions = (dispatch) => ({
  loadTasks: loadTaskList, //taskList Reducer
  selectTask: selectTask, //ActiveTask Reducer
  deleteTask: deleteTask, //TaskList Reducer
  newTask: newTask //activeTask Reducer
});
```

Comment: I think you need to assign the tasks to something in your component. It currently looks like your `this.props.loadTasks` doesn't do anything with the resulting payload, so it doesn't modify the state/props of your component.

Comment: the tasks object in the store is connected to the component in mapstate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not dispatching the `action`, use this:

```
dispatch({type: LOAD_TASKS, payload: tasks});
```

Instead of:

```
return({type: LOAD_TASKS, payload: tasks});
```

Return will not do anything.

Comment: ah... derp... yep, still getting used to redux too

Comment: facing issue ..?

Comment: sorry that was just me cringing at forgetting something. still a little off but it's at the reducer and connect function at this point. it'll get done.

Comment: i think it should be `let mapActions = (dispatch) => ({
  loadTasks: (user) => dispatch(loadTaskList(user),
});

`

Answer (score 0):

> UNSAFE_componentWillMount() is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we recommend using the constructor() instead for initializing state.

I would recommend the same or call loadTasks() in componentDidMount() {} instead of componentWillMount()